# Is the basket.js concept of caching scripts into localstorage still a good idea to use?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am working on a site for an **intranet**. I want to optimize for performance, and I know the script I am loading won't have frequent changes to it. Is it better to cache the string of it (from an xhttp request) into local storage along with an expiry time like an hour or so. And then load from local storage and insert dynamically into the DOM.

Does anyone know if this method is still a good one to use? The browser I need to use is IE11 (IE10 rendering mode). Or chrome 49.

Thanks

Comment: You are confusing between local storage of data obtained from server and caching of scripts which is automatically done by browser based on headers sent.

Comment: If in the end, if I just need to execute the javascript string, does it make a difference if I get it from local storage or make a get request and get it?

Answer (score 0):

Forget "still," as described this was never a good idea. The web browser can handle all of the caching for you, just set appropriate cache headers (in your case, to not bother to check back — not even an `If-Modified-Since` request — for an hour, as that's what you describe doing with local storage) and let the browser do its job.

Comment: What about this `Tests by Google and Bing have shown that there are performance benefits to caching assets in localStorage (especially on mobile) when compared to simply reading and writing from the standard browser cache. This project is currently working on replicating these tests in the public so that we have definitive statistics on whether this is true.`   

Doesn't this method avoid the need to make a get request to even check if there is a new file on server?

Comment: @omega: Where's that quote from? Caching headers can tell the browser not to even bother to make the request (that's what I meant by "not even an `If-Modified-Since` request) if the resource is within the valid period.

Comment: I could imagine a *very slight* benefit based on local storage having fewer things in it and thus being a faster lookup, but I wouldn't remotely consider it a reason for (ab)using local storage for caching purposes.

Comment: @omega: *"This project is currently working on replicating these tests in the public so that we have definitive statistics on whether this is true."* Yeah, without a citation, that's just waffle. :-) And the article it links to is about caching assets in general -- yes, some scripts, but it's far from actually saying there's a benefit to doing that in the general case vs. just using the browser's cache. Unless you have a proven speed problem, and then prove this solves it, I wouldn't add the complexity.

Comment: ("caching assets in general" -- in localStorage, I mean)